# Jupyter-notebook non-transparent plot surroundings when saving figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using jupyter-lab for plotting a dataframe.

```
fig = df.plot().get_figure()
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

Unfortunately, the surroundings of the plot (the space that is not between the x and y axis), where the coordinates are displayed are transparent, meaning a checkered grey-black pattern, which makes the coordinates practically unreadable. Is there any way of widening the non-transparent area so that the coordinates are included?

Comment: I think putting the image you are describing and the full code on it would help to resolve it faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can achieve this:

Update the [matplotlib rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html):

```py
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams.update({"figure.facecolor": "white"})
```

this will affect all the plots after you set this parameter in this script.

---

Set the figure facecolor for a single figure:

```py
fig = df.plot().get_figure()
fig.set_facecolor("white")
```